# Storing and modifying cached objects with redis

Tags: php, database, object, caching, redis

I am trying to cache php objects (representing database records) using redis.

I need to edit one field of many objects every once in a while, (the objects represent products and the quantity field should be updated often in bulk).

I came across different approaches in the internet like Hash tables and serialized json.

which is the best approach for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, based on my experience I would use definitively Hashes indexed by productId and product data stored as JSON objects. Don't use one key for every project since you can go with memory issues. Take a look at these links from Redis docs to understand why is better to use hashes instead of keys for your use case:

https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#use-hashes-when-possible
https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#using-hashes-to-abstract-a-very-memory-efficient-plain-key-value-store-on-top-of-redis

Apart from the structure to chose, I think it is also important to define if you are gonna store the complete product object or just the `quantity` field. I'm guessing you have your products in some database and you want to move to a cache, like Redis, the value of the quantity to improve performance, speed and to avoid read operations on your database. Probably I'm wrong but if that is the case, I would just create a hash indexed by `productId` and just with the `quantity` field as the value. Anyway if you need to also keep in cache some other fields from the product object, I'm not saying anything.

Another subject to consider that probably is not part of your question is how are you gonna update this quantity value in Redis hash, I'm also guessing you will decrease the quantity in Redis every time a product is sold, but it can happen that since a user go to product page and s/he decides to buy the product the number of products could be zero. So you should first update dynamically the counter of products in your web app from Redis to keep your users informed, and also before finalizing a purchase check the quantity of this product but against the database. What I mean is  that even using Redis, the source of truth is your database, and it can exist some sync issues between Redis and your database

Probably I've guessed a lot of things... :)